# WinXP Fails to boot. Stops at Checking file system on C: The volume is clean. windows has finished checking the disk

Tags: windows-xp, boot, troubleshooting

I have a WinXP machine that won't boot after installing the Lenovo ThinkVantage updates (which includes things like WIFI and video drivers).

Regular boot hangs just after the WinXP Splash Screen.

The machine fails to boot in Safe mode (mups.sys last line)

Complicating the matter is the machine has PointSec full disk encryption. Using UBCD4Win with the Pointsec plugin I can get access to the machines drive.

When I add the following boot.ini: /BASEVIDEO /BOOTLOG /SOS 
The machine does the following:
* PointSec Authentication
* List of drivers is displayed
* A blue info screen showing things like: 2 system processors, blah blah, boot logging is enabled

Then appears a black screen showing the message
    Checking file system on C: The volumne is clean. windows has finished checking the disk.

That is as far as the system gets. 
I am really stuck for ideas on how to fix this (manually trying to copy in the old drivers didn't seem to help), or even to determine which update is causing the problem.

I'd appreciate any trouble shooting tips for failed XP boot ups.

Comment: This advice may not help with your current problem, but may in the future, I always make a full disk image before doing any Updates of the OS or Drivers, ect, this way you can restore the image when you get into a situation like you currently are.
.

I hope you get things straightened out.

Comment: @Moab What tool do you use to make your full disk image? Will it work when full disk encryption is in place (i.e. Pointsec?)

Comment: I use Acronis, but there are some free ones like Macrium Reflect Free Edititon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually rolling back updates to a slaved disk requires two things.

1. Roll back the updates to c:\windows\system32 and c:\windows\system32\drivers 
   Check which files have a last modified (or created) timestamp close to the time of the problem. Search for backups of these files (using something like everything search which runs fine under ubcd4win)
   Original files can be found in places like: c:\windows\system32\reinstallbackups\008\DriverFiles
2. Revert the registry changes. 
   UBCD4Win provides a tool to do this:  Registry Restore Wizard. It basically just looks in the System Restore Directory c:\System Volume Information and lists all the available Restore Points . You can also do this manually using the following instructions:
   http://hypography.com/forums/tutorials-and-how-tos/17193-xp-recovery-instructions-for-ubcd4win.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the [Fixmbr](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/bootcons_fixmbr.mspx?mfr=true) tool from the Recovery Console.
Also (in the Recovery Console), Try to run CHKDSK /P.

Comment: Should CHKDSK /P be CHKDSK /F?

Comment: The Hard Disk is fully encrypted with PointSec encryption. I got the strong impression that it's a bad idea to try Fixmbr or chkdsk if you are running full disk encryption.

Comment: fixmbr, bad idea. chkdsk, maybe not.